# Can I use ultrasound to detect metal underground?

Tags: metals

I am doing research which aim to detect metal underground. I know that most metal detectors are based on the concept of change of inductance of an inductor caused by mutual inductance with a neighbouring metal or ferromagnetic material ([like this](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/other-gadgets/metal-detector.htm)). However, I want to find another way. I am not strong in physic so I would like to ask:

Is it possible to use ultrasound to detect metal which underground?

I am programmer and I use a module named [URM37 Ultrasound](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/URM37_V3.2_Ultrasonic_Sensor_(SKU:SEN0001)) as ultrasound unit.

Please anyone gives me anything guide to help me understand deeply.

Thanks so much.
Tan M.

Comment: Please tell me what's going on? What will happen with my post if it's put on hold?